# Joda's DateTime is inconsistent with java.util.Calendar

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I use the following code to check the consistency between joda's DateTime and java.util.Calendar. This result is correct, but if I change the year 2000 to 1900, then I will get 2 different result. Is this a bug or something else cause this ?

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(1900,0,1,0,0,0);  // Calendar's month is 0 based
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
System.out.println(c.getTimeInMillis() / 1000);
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1900,1,1,0,0,0);   // joda's month is 1 based
System.out.println(dt.getMillis() / 1000);
```

And this is the output

```
-2209017600
-2209017943
```

Comment: Mind showing what results you get specifically?

Comment: @Ambrish: Nope - months in Joda Time are 1-based, not 0-based.

Comment: Note that the code you've given so far wouldn't even compile as Java. It would help if you'd give a short but complete example, including the results, as Java.

Comment: I got proper result: Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(2000, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    System.out.println(c.getTimeInMillis() / 1000);
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    System.out.println(dt.getMillis() / 1000);

Comment: Agreed with @JonSkeet. I just took a best guess of what you meant, tested it and got matching answers, so keen to see what you actually wrote and the results you got.

Comment: Sorry guys. I have updated the code to be java program. And also paste the output

Comment: According to your [issue](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/334) on Joda-Time, you use Shanghai zone. Are you aware of the fact that Joda-Time and JDK use different tz data for 1900 (before 1927)?

Comment: @MenoHochschild Is there any reason to use different time zone between joda and JDK /

Comment: @zjffdu Joda-Time and JDK use separate time zone data. Joda-Time has decided to use all tzdb-entries including synthetical entries like LMT, JDK only use data entries since 1900.

Comment: @zjffdu And of course, separate time zone repositories can use different tzdb versions!

Answer (score 3):

It's something else :)

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime; 
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DateTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(1900,0,1,0,0,0);
        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        System.out.println(c.getTimeInMillis()/1000);
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(1900,1,1,0,0,0);
        System.out.println(dt.getMillis()/1000);
    }
}
```

result:

```
-2208992400
-2208992400

Process finished with exit code 0
```

*It has to do with offset between UTC and your timezone. For my timezone it is 1893*

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;  
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DateTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int i = 1900;
        boolean found = false;
        while (!found) {
            c.set(i,0,1,0,0,0);
            c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(i,1,1,0,0,0);
            found = !(c.getTimeInMillis() == dt.getMillis());
            if (found) {
                System.out.println("year: " + i);
                System.out.println(c.getTimeInMillis());
                System.out.println(dt.getMillis());
            }
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
year: 1893
-2429830800000
-2429830408000
```

This offset between UTC and set time-zone can be checked in time zone data base

Comment: it weird that I copy and paste this code, and I get 2 different result on intellij. I suspect it might be timezone issue, but even when I specify the same timezone, still get 2 different result.